# print values of a nested array php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

First let me say that I have gone through a lot of related question on here but none of them solve my issue. I have and php nested array in db and need to print the all the values. the output prints out the first top most array (which is the 'name', and values "Office , home") but does not get the nested array values which is contained in 'BB". 
this is my code:

```
function getTB($name='', $value='') {
$value    = json_decode($value);

$name = '';  $BB= ''; 
foreach ($value  as $key=>$val) {
    $name .= $val['name'].',';
```

JSON code:

```
[{"name":"Office","TB":[{"date":[false,true],"time":"8:00 AM"}]},{{"days":[false,true],"time":"6:00 PM"},
```

Comment: Are you printing the array out for debugging purposes? Perhaps `print_r` or `var_dump` may be of use (http://uk3.php.net/print_r http://uk3.php.net/var-dump)

Comment: no i need to print the information out in a doc which will be used later by a different program

Comment: Okay, so can you not just re-encode it in JSON format with `json_encode`?

Comment: @Pudge601 I do not understand your suggestion. My problem is that am unable to print out the entire array not with the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `array_walk_recursive`

for example if you have json like this (which is having a subarray)

```
$decoded = json_decode('{"abc": "one",
                         "def": "two",
                         "sub_array": {
                                 "ABC": "ONE"
                                 }}', true);

array_walk_recursive($decoded, function($value,$key) {
  echo $key.' :'.$value.'<br>';
});
```

the output will be

```
abc :one
def :two
ABC :ONE
```

so use like this instead of normal foreach

***Update***

use like this

```
$arr='[{"name":"Office","TB":[{"date":[false,true],"time":"8:00 AM"},{"days":[false,true],"time":"6:00 PM"}]}]';

$rr=json_decode($arr);

foreach ($rr[0]->TB as $key => $value) {
array_walk_recursive($value, function($k,$kk){
     echo 'Key is '.$kk.' & Value is '.$k.'<br>';   
});
}
```

***output:***

```
Key is 0 & Value is 

Key is 1 & Value is 1

Key is time & Value is 8:00 AM

Key is 0 & Value is 

Key is 1 & Value is 1

Key is time & Value is 6:00 PM
```

Comment: i get this error when i tried your code: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. I will update the question with the structure of my array

Comment: try `array_walk_recursive($decoded[0]->TB, functio...`

Comment: can you post the json code,with out decoding it..? which looks like `{abc:adad...}`

Comment: you can access each subarray like this `$rr[0]->TB[0]` and `$rr[0]->TB[1]`

Comment: this does not return as well.. maybe this function does not imply in my case